# QGIS 3d visualisation of polygons

Tags: qgis, 3d

I'm working on a dataset from an excavation collected by an ancient total station. I have a point layer with point code, xyz values and a description of the point. These points are corners of features, lines around features etc etc. They need to be converted to polygons/lines to make sense of all the different features. The problem is that this site is extremely complicated because it consists of a lot of (partial) inhumations on top of eachother. A 3d visualisation of this data would be perfect to analyse this dataset. A 3d visualisation of the points is easy using qgis2threejs. I would like to know how i add the z values from the points and add them to (to be created) polygons so i can create a 3d visualisation of the polygons?

Comment: dude...not knowing the english name, it took me a while to realize we're not talking about mysterious ancient *total gas station* crypts...

Comment: heh well that would be an amazing story :P

Comment: ,) anyways, how's that data stored, how do the attributes look like? you'd need a field with the z-coords to be used as height. possibly extract them from *xyz* using the field calculator. could you post an example of your data structure?

Comment: I have 6 columns: point id, x, y, z, empty one that needs to be removed, and description. I've used the field calculator for newly created points before but i can't get that to work for polygons. If i create a new polygon based on four corner points (coffin) there's no x,y,z data. I'm trying to find a way to get the xyz data from the points and add that to the newly created polygon. I could enter it manually but that would take a ridiculous amount of time.

Comment: okay, edit your question with the info from the comment. since you 'merge' 4 points with individual attributes into one polygon, you´d also have to collect/average those values into one. however, I`m sorry to say: much of what you want to try here will not work with the plugin. it´s doing a great job at placing buildings on terrain, but it works mainly with basic *three.js* 3D object primitives and extruded geometries based on one height attribute; without altering the scene objects/geometries codewise, you won´t get your coffins neatly on top of each other...

Comment: you could dive into native *three.js*...but setting up complex volumes would take some time to learn, if you´re not very familiar with JavaScript, it´s data types and possibly GLSL. since I´m working a lot with *three.js* I might be tempted to offer to set up a scene for you, in time, if you can upload the data somewhere and link here

Comment: Hm too bad. If I manually enter a single z value for a polygon it kinda works but it's not exactly precise.

Comment: if you use the field calcualtor to create those polygons, try to set the height attribute by using the *avg()* function (i.e. average between all four z values)

Comment: I have no idea how to create polygons with the field calculator. Until now i've created them manually in a new layer. Thanks for the suggestion i'll try to find a tuturial somewhere and experiment a bit to figure out how to do that. I usually only end up here if i'm trying to do something i've never done before and my google fu lets me down :)

Comment: do you have an attribute that can be used to group all 4 points per polygon? I´ll add an asnwer using `Virtual Layers` to get you up to the point where you can try using your data with the plugin, then.

Comment: Maybe if I manually add a column with just the feature number. the point ID's consist of a feature number followed by a subnumber (141-1, 141-2 etc) bit that includes points around the skull, points on limbs etc etc. The data collection is extremely limited with the total station we had in the field. Just point I'd and xyz. The descriptions need to be written down in a Fieldbook :S